# Как добавить php код в twig шаблонизатор

Tags: php, mvc, symfony2, twig

Есть сайт на symfony, который использует twig шаблонизатор. Внутри twiga нельзя писать пхп код, а это очень нужно. Заменить его теми функциями что есть в twig нельзя. Ведь это не что-то нестандартное, должен быть простой способ выполнить пхп и выдать результат в шаблон. 
Есть:

```
abstract class BaseContentController extends BaseController
{
    // ...
    public function loadUrlPageAction($url)
    {
       $page = $this->getContentService()->getPageByUrl($url);
       return $this->returnPage($page);
    }
    // ...
}
```

возможно тут что-то надо изменить?

Что в PHP: Там находится класс, который берёт имя домена и урл и отправляет посредством `fsockopen()` на удалённый сервер. Думаю, твигом такое сделать нельзя.

UPD: Хочу сделать для этого сервис.

В файле /Resources/config/services.yml :

```
services:
# Расширения Twig'a
twig.rsr_extension:
    class: Site\RsrSecurityBundle\Twig\RsrSecurityExtension
    arguments: ["@translator"]
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }

rsr.content:
    class:  Site\RsrSecurityBundle\Service\RsrContentService
    parent: submarine.content
    calls:
       - [setPaginator, ["@knp_paginator"]]

rsr.sendurl:
    class: Site\RsrSecurityBundle\Service\RsrNwlSystem
    tags:
        - { name: sendurl }
```

rsr.sendurl мой добавленный сервис.
По пути `Site\RsrSecurityBundle\Service\RsrNwlSystem.php` находится мой класс. Как тут указать ключ сервиса, чтобы им воспользоваться в классе вывода основного контента на страницу.

Comment: Было бы неплохо, если бы в вопросе было написано что выхотите написать и почему это обязательно делать средствами php

Comment: обновил описание

Comment: И действительно Twig на это не способен. Но почему на этот функционал вообще нужно завязывать шаблонизатор? Вы ведь в него передаете все параметры. Почему на этом этапе нельзя обрабатывать эти данные (до формирования страницы)? Ну и ответ на ваш вопрос я уже дал.

Comment: **ПОСРЕДСТВОМ**

Comment: Прошу прощения, забыл уточнить что после сервер возвращает ссылку я должен вывести её на странице. Поэтому и завязан на шаблоне.

Comment: `rsr.sendurl` и есть ключ, по которму зарегистрирован сервис

Answer (score 7):

> Внутри twiga нельзя писать пхп код, а это очень нужно.

Это не нужно. Это официальная позиция разработчиков твига, и очень правильная: **твиг занимается шаблонизацией**. Он **выводит данные**. Это называется **принципом единственной ответственности**, и это не чья-то прихоть. Если вы думаете иначе - то это, грубо говоря, ваши проблемы и ваш недостаток квалификации. Задача подготовки данных, отправляемых в шаблон - это задача контроллера, причем сам он эти данные недолжен создавать, он должен использовать **модели** и **сервисы** для получения и модификации данных, а генерировать их не вправе.

> Ведь это не что-то нестандартное

Это что-то нестандартное.

Ваше обращение к серверу должно находиться в сервисе и вызываться контроллером.

Comment: Я этот недостаток квалификации и пытаюсь восполнить) Сервис слишком популярное слово чтобы гуглить, можете уточнить в каком направлении смотреть информацию о сервисах и работе с ними.

Comment: Если у вас вторая симфони, то реализуете класс, который занимается вышеописанным и добавляете новой записью в `Resources/config/services.yml` бандла. В контроллере по ключу его получаете, запрашиваете необходимые данные.

Comment: Апдейтнул основной вопрос, извиняюсь за глупые вопросы, но как задать ключ для добавленного сервиса и в контроллере его получить? Как потом вызвать метод из моего класса, чтобы результат работы передать потом в шаблон и уже наконец вывести его?

Comment: @Raftko https://gist.github.com/etki/04903718b1095ebdd7b0

Comment: Ерунду вы пишите, уважаемый... Twig далеко не только выводит данные и занимается непосредственно шаблонизацией, если бы это было так, вы бы подготавливали данные для отрисовки в контроллере, не то какие данные отрисовывать, а как. Судя по вашей логике вообще непонятно зачем в Twig к примеру оператор set, зачем вводить новые переменные, если мы только отрисовываем то, что нам дали? Twig намного и намного большее. По сабжу - нельзя использовать php теги напрямую, необходимо создавать свои фильтры или функции и реализовывать механику там.

Answer (score 0):

Создайте новый фильтр, функцию или тег (в зависимости от ваших требований). В Twig это достойно описано в [документации](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html)

Учитывая изменения в вопросе, поясню. Вы можете создать дополнительный фильтр (назову его `urlsend`) и вызывать его в шаблоне для нужных переменных, например

`{{ var.url|urlsend }}`

Сам фильтр - это любая функция (или метод), которая получает одно значение на вход и выдает результат "фильтрации". Подключается это очень просто (например ваш фильтр это функция `sendURL()`:

```
$filter = new Twig_SimpleFilter('urlsend', 'sendURL');
$twig->addFilter($filter);
```

Comment: Я не совсем понял в документации в каком файле создаются пользовательские фильтры. И почему фильтр а не функцию? По-моему фильтр должен что-то фильтровать или в твиге не обязательно?

Comment: Это может быть в любом файле, откуда доступен экземпляр шаблонизатора. Вы можете ничего не фильтровать, просто вернуть то же значение, но перед эти выполнить необходимые вам действия.

Comment: Я добавил в уже существовавший сервис:
$filter = new Twig_SimpleFilter('urlsend', function ($string) {
  return 123;
  });
а в твиг шаблон :
{{ "123"|urlsend }}
Это приводит к 500 ошибки сервера.
Эррор репортинг в app.php не помог.
Не ясно что с этми делать. Что я делаю не так?